# dynamic table rending table row contents having an issue in android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

Hi in the below code displaying dynamic table row named as below in my code .Rows also adding dynamically inside table contents displaying from the api and adding to the textviews.

In the below code I am facing an issue t1v.setText(namesList[i]); for the text is having some names and adding to the array list.

In the same way I am using another for loop second for loop want to execute outside the first for loop.unit price is having an issue.

output for the below code:

```
Sl.No      Product Name       Quantity   Unit Price           
 0         Fac                  1       87000 67000 78900     
 1         CS                   1       87000 67000 78900     
 2         BS                   1       87000 67000 78900
```

Expected output:
Sl.No      Product Name       Quantity   Unit Price
     0         Fac                  1       87000
     1         CS                   1       67000
     2         BS                   1       78900

```
TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.tables);
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
        Resources resource = getContext().getResources();
        tbrow0.setBackgroundColor(resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1));
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv1.setText(" Product Name ");
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv2.setText(" Quantity");
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv3.setText(" Unit Price ");
        tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);
        TextView tv4 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv4.setText(" Total ");
        tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tbrow0.addView(tv4);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);
        String[] namesList = productValues.split(",");
        String[] priceList=listprices.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
            TextView t0v = new TextView(getContext());
            t0v.setText("" + i);
            t0v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t0v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t0v);

            TextView t1v = new TextView(getContext());
            t1v.setText(namesList[i]);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
          //  stk.addView(tbrow);

            TextView t2v = new TextView(getContext());
            t2v.setText(quantitys);
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
//            stk.addView(tbrow);
            for(int j=0;j<priceList.length;j++) {
                TextView t3v = new TextView(getContext());
                String rupee = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                t3v.setText(rupee.concat(priceList[j]));
                t3v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t3v);

//               stk.addView(tbrow);
            }


            TextView t4v = new TextView(getContext());
            //  String t2 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(qty) * Integer.parseInt(list_price));
            String rupee = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
            t4v.setText(totals);
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);
            stk.addView(tbrow);

        }
```

Comment: You should work on making your actual issue + question clearer. You would almost never write code like this in any meaningful/real implementation, so I'm unsure what problem you're running into.

Comment: unit price  87000 67000 78900  one time want to display like product name having unit price

Comment: like Fac product unitprice is 87000 and cs unit price is 670000 like this

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by these comments. Please try to describe what you want without concrete examples. It might convey the issue better.

Comment: @mawalker check my expected output

Comment: @mawalker did you understand